# Converting Years to Water Years Matplotib Visualization

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, time-series

Thank you in advance for your help! (Code Below)  (Data: [Here](https://github.com/the-datadudes/deepSoilTemperature/blob/master/AllDeepSoilData.zip?raw=true))

My visualization starts from Day 0 (Jan-1) and goes until the end of the year (Shown Below)
I am trying to make the visualization represent water years (EX:Oct-1st-2018 - Sept-30th-2019) instead of conventional years. The year would start on Oct1 and the end of the year would be Sept 30th How would I go about making that change?

```
selected_soil_station = 'Minot'

#Importing data, creating a copy, and assigning it to a variable
raw_data = pd.read_csv('all-deep-soil-temperatures.csv', index_col=1, parse_dates=True)
df_all_stations = raw_data.copy()

#Setting the program to iterate based off of the station of the users choice
df_selected_station = df_all_stations[df_all_stations['Station'] == selected_soil_station]
df_selected_station.fillna(method = 'ffill', inplace=True);
#df_selected_station.head()   ##Just for checking what the dataframe looks like at this point

# Indexes the data by day and creates a column that keeps track of the day
df_selected_station_D=df_selected_station.resample(rule='D').mean()
df_selected_station_D['Day'] = df_selected_station_D.index.dayofyear
#df_selected_station_D.head()

#Assigning variable so that mean represents df_selected_station_D but indexed by day
mean=df_selected_station_D.groupby(by='Day').mean()
mean['Day']=mean.index

#This inserts a new column named 'Topsoil' at the end that represents the average between 5 cm, 10 cm, and 20 cm
mean['Topsoil']=mean[['5 cm', '10 cm','20 cm']].mean(axis=1)


#Creating range columns for the line graph to use 
maxx=df_selected_station_D.groupby(by='Day').max()
minn=df_selected_station_D.groupby(by='Day').min()
#maxxxx=df_selected_station_D.groupby(by='Day').max()
#minnnn=df_selected_station_D.groupby(by='Day').min()
mean['maxx05']=maxx['5 cm']
mean['minn05']=minn['5 cm']
mean['maxx10']=maxx['10 cm']
mean['minn10']=minn['10 cm']
mean['maxx20']=maxx['20 cm']
mean['minn20']=minn['20 cm']

#Averaging theme and returning the lowest average for that date
mean['maxTopsoil']=mean[['maxx05', 'maxx10','maxx20']].mean(axis=1)
mean['minTopsoil']=mean[['minn05', 'minn10','minn20']].mean(axis=1)


#mean['topsoilMax']=maxx['Topsoil']
#mean['topsoilMin']=minn['Topsoil']

#mean.head()

#Creating the visualization

plt.style.use('ggplot')
bx = mean.plot(x='Day', y='Topsoil',color='black')
plt.fill_between(mean['Day'],mean['minTopsoil'],mean['maxTopsoil'],color='blue',alpha = 0.2);
bx.set_xlabel("Day of the year")
bx.set_ylabel("Temperature in Celsius")
bx.set_title("Soil Temp, Air Temp, and Snow Depth for " + str(selected_soil_station))

# x axis label and title for graph
```

What I have:

[image]

What I want (Of course the graph would also look different if the dates changed haha:

[image]

Comment: How do you want to map the 356 days to 60 days?

Comment: What do you mean? It would still be a year. The year would start on Oct1 and the end of the year would be Sept 30th

Comment: @runDOSrun a water year is defined as the period between October 1st of one year and September 30th of the next.

Comment: I am not sure why I was down-voted. Was my question not clear?

Comment: Have you tried shifting by the number of days to Oct 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need a way to calculate the water year day number. One example is:

```
import datetime as dt

def day_of_water_year(some_date):
    # Get the date of the previous October 1st
    water_year_start_date = dt.datetime(some_date.year + some_date.month // 10 - 1, 10, 1)
    
    # Return the number of days since then
    return (some_date - water_year_start_date).days + 1
```

The 'Day' column in your dataframe currently stores the normal day number, to change it to the water year day number all you need to do is change the following line:

```
df_selected_station_D['Day'] = df_selected_station_D.index.dayofyear
```

to:

```
df_selected_station_D['Day'] = df_selected_station_D.index.to_series().apply(day_of_water_year)
```